# How can Jquery window.location.hash replace?

Tags: jquery, url, hash, tabs, replace

How can i change 
http://www.example.com/#home to http://www.example.com/home

I'm using jquery tabs

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pushState` will do this, though support isn't so great.

Read up here: http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate?16328a60

Comment: i cant ? my code http://jsfiddle.net/LvsJB/

Answer (score 0):

You may try the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function:

```
str = str.replace('#', '');
```

Comment: i cant ? my code http://jsfiddle.net/LvsJB/